# non-passive event listener violation with on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange, passive-event-listeners

So, I keep getting this non-passive event listener violation for my on change event. It only started this nonsense recently. After I moved the .js file into it's own folder, this function stopped working completely. The function will not even be executed, i just get the warning instead. Every function in the .js file works except for this one.

The error:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking >'mousewheel' 
>      event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more 
>      responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

The Code:

```
    //Put the music into the list for the user to select from
    $('#songs').on('change', function() {
    var $selected = $('#songs').find(':selected').text();
    $('#audio').attr('src', './../music/' + $selected);
    });

    <div class="control-panel">
    <audio src="music/Legend_of_Zelda_Zelda_Heineken_OC_ReMix.mp3" 
    id="audio" controls>Audio not supported</audio>
    <select id="songs">
    </select>
    </div>
```

Everything I've seen about non-passive problems has to deal with functions that have .preventDefault() or modify the page based on scroll behavior. I don't know why my on change function is triggering it, so I don't know how to make it stop triggering it either.

--edit--
some more information about the nature of the bug:

It only stops the change from being transmitted to the audio element.
The warning is sent the moment the selector is clicked.
This code worked for months, the error came latter without any changes in this code preceding it.
none of my other code is being effected by the bug.

--Edit 2--
now that the code is working (by removing jQuery use) I have only one question:
**why is the warning still there?**

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the title it should be "on change" not "on click". However the warning is sent the moment I click on the selector, not after I've changed it. So, I suppose in a way it's not wrong...

Comment: I wonder if jQuery uses a `scroll` event hack to fix some event types or something else. What browsers do you support? Maybe just don't use jQuery.

Comment: i'm only actively supporting chrome right now. The jQuery has never caused me a problem before, but it's worth trying anything new at this point.

Comment: If you're only supporting Chrome, which probably means no very, very old versions, then I'd drop jQuery. There's just no reason for it. Do you get the error with this code? https://jsfiddle.net/uy5dm787/

Comment: @doodlemeister The select element has a list of strings of the song file names. it puts the selected one into the src of the audio element.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at loadAudio.js:18

Comment: Then you're not waiting for the DOM to be ready before it runs. Here's an update: https://jsfiddle.net/uy5dm787/5/

Comment: HAZZZA!!! it's working! I still get the warning, like before, but at least it's working.

Comment: Thank you! I may have to rethink my use of jQuery in this project.

Comment: Odd about the warning. Not sure what else to say.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery was really handy several years ago. Today it's easy to get by without big libraries.

Comment: @doodlemeister If you put that code and explanation in an answer, then I can mark it as answered. If you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't know what causes that error, it could be related to some stuff jQuery needs to do under the hood.

In general, you can do this without jQuery, so here's a rewrite in pure JS.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.querySelector('#songs').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var t = document.querySelector('#songs :checked').text;
    document.querySelector('#audio').src = './../music/' + t;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

es hat **nichts** mit JS oder jQuery zu tun. Ausgelöst wird der Fehler durch das ***<select>***-Tag ich benutze Chrome 
Version 65.0.3325.181 (Offizieller Build) (64-Bit)

```html
&lt;label class="control-label" for="bemerkung"&gt;
Wie sind Sie auf uns auf­merk­sam ge­wor­den?&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;select class="form-control" id="aufmerksam_durch_dropdown" name="Aufmerksam"&gt;
&lt;option value="" selected="selected"  class="default"&gt;Pick one&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="1"&gt;Durch das In­ter­net&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="2"&gt;Durch Freun­de/Be­kann­te/Fa­mi­lie&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="3"&gt;Durch ein Mit­glied&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="4"&gt;Durch eine Ver­an­stal­tung&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;option value="0"&gt;Son­sti­ge&lt;/option&gt;
&lt;/select&gt;

<label class="control-label" for="bemerkung">
Wie sind Sie auf uns auf­merk­sam ge­wor­den?<br />
</label>
<select class="form-control" id="aufmerksam_durch_dropdown" name="Aufmerksam">
<option value="" selected="selected"  class="default">Pick one</option>
<option value="1">Durch das In­ter­net</option>
<option value="2">Durch Freun­de/Be­kann­te/Fa­mi­lie</option>
<option value="3">Durch ein Mit­glied</option>
<option value="4">Durch eine Ver­an­stal­tung</option>
<option value="0">Son­sti­ge</option>
</select>
```

Consolenmeldung: 
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952